# Transferring Data from one sheet column to another sheet different column with criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to transfer specific Cells from one sheet to another as long as the criteria is met. The criteria is Cell X="Yes"
I would prefer only to transfer the data I need and not an entire row because the next sheet I will be adding more data in.

```
Sheet1 "B3" needs to go to sheet2 "C3"
Sheet1 "C3" needs to go to sheet2 "D3"
Sheet1 "D3" needs to go to Sheet2 "E3"
Sheet1 "E3" needs to go to Sheet2 "F3"
```

This is where it starts to get messy

```
Sheet1 "G3" needs to go to Sheet2 "G3"
Sheet1 "H3" needs to go to Sheet2 "H3"
Sheet1 "J3" needs to go to Sheet2 "I3"
Sheet1 "K3" needs to go to Sheet2 "J3"
Sheet1 "M3" needs to go to Sheet2 "K3"
Sheet1 "Q3" needs to go to Sheet2 "M3"
Sheet1 "R3" needs to go to Sheet2 "N3"
Sheet1 "S3" needs to go to Sheet2 "O3"
Sheet1 "U3" needs to go to Sheet2 "Q3"
Sheet1 "V3" needs to go to Sheet2 "R3"
Sheet1 "W3" needs to go to Sheet2 "S3"
Sheet1 "X3" needs to go to Sheet2 "T3"
Sheet1 "Y3" needs to go to Sheet2 "U3"
Sheet1 "Z3" needs to go to Sheet2 "V3"
Sheet1 "AA3" needs to go to Sheet2 "W3" 
Sheet1 "AB3" needs to go to Sheet2 "X3"
```

I can paste and hide columns that wouldn't be a problem as long as the first goes into sheet 3 where it needs to and stops where the last one is so it doesn't erase things I add to the next columns.
I would paste what I am trying to use but it is probably all wrong and would only make for confusion

Comment: Can you just us an `=IF()` formula. In Sheet2 `C3` put the formula `=If(Sheet1!X1="Yes", Sheet1!B3, "")` That tests to see if "Yes" is in Sheet1 X3, if so then it grabs Sheet1 B3, otherwise it puts nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but here is what you can do. All you need to do is to add whatever information you want after the `Then`

```
Sub Class()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim i, j As Integer

    'Where do you want to start to copy your information
    'i = row
    'j = column
    i = 2
    j = 1

    On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    'Instead of D3:D7, enter the range of your Yes,No cells
    'Change Cells(c.Row, c.Column - 1) to whatever cells you want to copy (mines were left to my yes or no cells
    For Each c In Range("O3:O37")
        If c.Value = "Yes" Then
            Sheets("Feuil1").Range(Cells(c.Row, c.Column - 14), Cells(c.Row, c.Column + 14)).Copy Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(i, j)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next c

    Exit Sub

    Errorcatch:
        MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

#### Edit

I followed your drive and succesfully updated the code to produce the tab "Yes".

Hope this helps,
Luisarcher.

Comment: I will attach my sheets for you to see exactly what I am trying to do. Maybe this will help narrow down what we are talking about. I added a sheet for you to view that shows the formula I am using but I have to use a middle sheet I call "Yes" and then a formula to transfer from there. I then run into a problem down the line in sheet later because of that formula. That is why I would prefer to transfer the data Directly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, i changed the code to get the "Yes" tab from your "Offer" tab (tested and it worked). However, I'm not quite sure I understand what you need.